# Convert string to ISO date format

Tags: date, typescript

How can I transform this date format :

```
Wed Jan 04 2017 18:19:13 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

To ISO date format?

If I do:

```
let date = new Date(value);
```

On Browser and Android works fine but when I use on IOS it returns a invalid date error

Thanks

Comment: Is the date **always** in that format?

Comment: it comes from API in this format

Comment: Is that a yes or a no?

Comment: yes. It comes with this format always

Comment: Only RFC2822 or ISO8601 formats are guaranteed to work. In your case you can use a regex to transform the date into RFC2822 format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse